How to execute SQL UPDATE query form "Google looker studio" to the PostgreSQL?
Is it possible for Google Looker Studio to send SQL queries to change data in PostgreSQL DB?
Where to see examples?

As far as I know, Looker Studio is built for analytics purposes so it will only support reading data but not writing it back or updating rows in your database.
